# SOM out of memory in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to use SOM to learn 80000X10 samples (each sample is a vector of size 10). But I can't even configure 8x8 net with 10000X1 samples. It throws "out of memory" error.

Here is my code (data is 80000X10 matrix):

```
net=selforgmap([8 8])
net=configure(net,data(1:10000,1))
```

Matlab help: "Unconfigured networks are automatically configured and initialized the first time train is called."

Even for 8000X1 dataset, it takes a lot of time. I noticed a huge `numWeightElements: 512000` in `net` variable (8*8*8000=512000). The weights should be 8*8. SOM training algorithm shouldn't use this much memory. What is wrong?

The output of memory command:

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:               3014 MB (3.160e+009 bytes) 
Memory available for all arrays:      3014 MB (3.160e+009 bytes) 
Memory used by MATLAB:                1154 MB (1.210e+009 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):                4040 MB (4.236e+009 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your configuring wrong the input structure. Each input vector must be a column and not a row. Quote from this "[Clustering Data - MATLAB & Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/clustering-data.html)"

> To define a clustering problem, simply arrange Q input vectors to be
>   clustered as columns in an input matrix (see "[Data Structures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/data-structures.html)"
>   for a detailed description of data formatting for static and time
>   series data). For instance, you might want to cluster this set of 10
>   two-element vectors:
>
> inputs = [7 0 6 2 6 5 6 1 0 1; 6 2 5 0 7 5 5 1 2 2]

As you can see each input vector is a column. You have 10 two element input vectors as a 2x10 array.